# PHP Login Page Always Returning Incorrect Username and Password

Tags: php, xml, authentication

I have a basic login page that takes user inputted username and password and checks the entered details against an XML document with user details.

The problem is, even if the username and password are correct the PHP document is still displaying that the credentials are incorrect.

Thanks

```
<?php

    if(isset($_GET['login'])) {

        $id = "";
        $errors = "";
        $dom = DomDocument::load('../../data/customer.xml');

        if(empty($_GET['email'])) {
            $errors .= "Email field cannot be empty <br />";
        }
        else {
            $inputEmail = $_GET['email'];
        }
        if(empty($_GET['password'])) {
            $errors .= "Password field cannot be empty <br />";
        }
        else {
            $inputPassword = $_GET['password'];
        }

        if(isset($inputEmail) && isset($inputPassword)) {

            $email = $dom->getElementsByTagName('email');
            $password = $dom->getElementsByTagName('password');

            for($i = 0; $i < $email->length; $i++) {
                if($inputEmail == $email->item($i)->textContent && $inputPassword == $pwd->item($i)->textContent) {
                    $id = $dom->getElementsByTagName("id")->item($i)->textContent;
                    break; 
                }
            }

        }

        if($id == "") {
            $errors .= "Incorrect username or password";
        } 

        if($errors == "" ) {
            echo true;
        }
        else {
            echo $errors;
        }

    }
?>
```

As requested, here an example of the XML:

```
<customers>
    <details>
        <firstname>Example</firstname>
        <lastname>Example</lastname>
        <email>example@email.com</email>
        <id>1</id>
        <password>cb750e88</password>
    </details>
</customers>
```

Comment: Please, provide example of XML. (Change sensitive data)

Comment: Check if your $dom contains what you expect it to contain (Do a vardump)

Comment: shouldn't it be checking $_POST instead of $_GET

Comment: @FirstOne Added an excerpt of the XML.

Comment: Did you make sure that the contents of your xml document are being loaded correctly? If they are, could you try comparing the username and password using === instead of ==? I assume they're both strings, so this should force a literal comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are Taking `$pwd` variable instead of `$password` :

```
if($inputEmail == $email->item($i)->textContent && $inputPassword == $pwd->item($i)->textContent) {
```

Replace It :

```
if($inputEmail == $email->item($i)->textContent && $inputPassword == $password->item($i)->textContent) {
```

Comment: I can't believe I missed that typo. thanks for the help!